# Какие нужны настройки SQL Server для работы с FILESTREAM и sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats?

Tags: sql-server, windows-service

Мы оформляем наши сервера как службы Windows. Сервера, которые хранят данные в xml-файлах, работают без проблем. Сервера, которые хранят данные в БД MS SQL Server, работают недостаточно хорошо. Обычно мы используем Windows-аутентификацию при подключении к БД MS SQL Server, но так как по умолчанию службы Windows работают под системной учётной записью, аутентификация при подключении к БД не проходит.

Тогда мы запускаем службы под учётной записью пользователя Windows, которого заводим на сервере БД. Этот вариант работает довольно нестабильно: пара перезапусков машины - и пароль пользователя теряется, служба не стартует с сообщением "Служба не запущена из-за ошибки входа в систему". Кроме того, если пользователь беспарольный, службу запустить под его учёткой невозможно.

Тогда мы переходим на аутентификацию SQL Server, и тут снова начинаются проблемы. Служба успешно подключается к серверу БД, но на некоторых операциях отваливается. Пока мы столкнулись с тем, что созданному пользователю не хватает прав на две вещи:

- Запросы к системному представлению sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
- Чтение и запись файлов, хранящихся в БД через SqlFileStream

В какие группы надо включить пользователя и какие серверные роли ему дать, чтобы не было этих проблем? Желательно скриптами, чтобы сделать в конфигурационной утилите кнопочку, по которой это будет автоматически происходить.

Или, может быть, объясните, что надо сделать, чтобы пароль пользователя не слетал?

Answer (score 1):

1  Для динамических административных представлений и функций в области сервера -  необходимо разрешение VIEW SERVER STATE на сервере, в области базы данных - необходимо разрешение VIEW DATABASE STATE на базе данных.

2  Если для хранения данных объектов FILESTREAM типа varbinary(max), выбрана файловая система, то учет.запись SQL Server должна иметь NTFS-права на доступ к контейнерам, раздача прав внутри SQL Server – обычным образом.
FILESTREAM разрешён при доступе через Transact-SQL ?

Comment: FullAccess стоит